# JUnit Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, junit, plugins

I feel stupid for not being able to find this, but where is the JUnit plugin for Eclipse? I've included the latest `.jar` in my buildpath, but I still don't have the option to create a new test case, run test cases with the green/red bar, etc. I need the plugin for this, right?

**EDIT:** I'm using "Eclipse for PHP Developers". So perhaps that wouldn't include JUnit automatically. Do I have to download Eclipse again, or can I just get that functionality somehow?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

JUnit is part of [Eclipse Java Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) (JDT). So, either install the JDT via *Software Updates* or download and install [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/java.php) (actually, I'd recommend installing [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) if you want a complete  built-in environment for server side development).

You add it to a project by right clicking the project in the Package Explorer and selecting *Build Path -> Add Libraries...* Then simply select JUnit and click *Next >*.

Answer (score 34):

It's built in Eclipse since ages. Which Eclipse version are you using? How were you trying to create a new JUnit test case? It should be *File* > *New* > *Other* > *Java - JUnit - JUnit Test Case* (you can eventually enter Filter text "junit").

Comment: actually, I'm using PHP Eclipse (see above). Can this be fixed, or do I need to download again?

Comment: I am not sure about that, sorry. But if you can't find it anywhere in the list, then I recommend to go get "Eclipse for Java developers" (or "Eclipse for Java EE developers" if you like to play with Java/JSP/Servlet webapps as well) and then add the PHP plugin afterwards.

Comment: I can't find the Junit package fore eclipse after googleing around a bit, so I think your best bet would just be to download a java version of eclipse.

Comment: @aubreyrhodes FYI, it's included in the JDT.

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to add the Java Development Tools by selecting *'Help'* -> *'Install New Software'*, there you select the *'Juno'* update site, then *'Programming Languages'* -> *'Eclipse Java Development Tools'*.

After that, you will be able to run your JUnit tests with *'Right Click'* -> *'Run as'* -> *'JUnit test'*.

Answer (score 11):

You do not need to install or update any software for the JUnit. it is the part of Java Development tools and comes with almost most of the latest versions in Eclipse.

Go to your project. Right click onto that->Select buildpath->add library->select JUnit from the list
->select the version you want to work with-> done

build you project again to see the errors gone:)

Answer (score 4):

Junit is included by default with Eclipse (at least the Java EE version I'm sure).  You may just need to add the view to your perspective.

Comment: Just a note, J2EE is renamed Java EE since a year or three.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has built in JUnit functionality. Open your Run Configuration manager to create a test to run. You can also create JUnit Test Cases/Suites from New->Other.

Answer (score 0):

---

Maybe you're in the wrong perspective?

Eclipse has a construct called a "perspective"; it's a task-oriented arrangement of windows, toolbar buttons, and menus.  There's a Java perspective, a Debug perspective, there's probably a PHP perspective, etc.  If you're not in the Java perspective, you won't see some of the buttons you expect (like New Class).

To switch perspectives, see the long-ish buttons on the right side of the toolbar, or use the Window menu.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out Quick JUnit: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-junit

The plugin is stable and it allows switching between production and test code. I am currently using Eclipse Mars 4.5 and the plugin is supported for this release as well as for the following:

Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1)