# I installed Eclipse for PHP, but want to add Java/JUnit

Tags: eclipse, junit

I have Eclipse for PHP developers installed, which I need. However, I also want to do Java/JUnit development. I'm expecting to see "File -> New -> JUnit test case", but it's not there.

Am I crazy? I've tried looking through the Eclipse Marketplace but I don't see it there either. I've downloaded the junit4.9b .JAR, and included it in my project, but I'm looking for that nice JUnit view in Eclipse, and the integrated way of running JUnit tests.

I also found this:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/swtbot/helios/dev-build/org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.test.junit4-2.0.4.20110304_0338-e5aff47-dev-e36.zip

... but not sure (a) if this is what I need, and (b) if so, how to install it.

My "File -> New" menu looks like this image:
[image]

Comment: Did you switched to Java perspective and have your project Java nature?

Comment: Yup, I'm in the Java perspective, and I'm writing a Java project. It compiles and everything, no worries, just can't find the UI-based way to run the tests. I'm guessing the "Eclipse for PHP Developers" doesn't come pre-packaged with JUnit?

Comment: Ok. What is if you choose `File -> New -> Other` and the type JUnit in dialog?

Comment: Thought of that - JUnit isn't there. I added an image of it just now so you can see what I see.

Comment: I only can suggest you to download Eclipse IDE for Java developers and use it with the same namespace for Java projects. Maybe the problem is some missed feature in PHP bundle :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very similar: 
[JUnit Eclipse Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962567/junit-eclipse-plugin)

As that accepted answer states, you should be able to get the JUnit plugin as part of the Java Development Tools (JDT).

It also looks like you can download the JUnit plugin directly here,

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.2-201102101200/index.php#JUnitPlugin

Comment: Hm, the download came down fine, and the MD5 sum checks out, but the installation fails. There might be something else wrong with my installation. I'll look elsewhere. The link you provided is what I'm looking for, but it look like my issue goes deeper than that.