# Eclipse : Creating and simultaneously running multiple test cases

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, plugins, testcase

I have written an application in Java using `Eclipse Luna` IDE. On paper I know the test cases required to test all branches/aspects of my application.

Does "eclipse alone" allow us to write test cases and execute it ?

I am specifically interested in being able to run all these tests cases in one click.

Something like this will help test the complete application with just onclick.

Comment: Questions asking for tool or library recommendations aren't a good fit for the StackOverflow format, so I'm voting to close this question. However, to answer your question, popular frameworks used JUnit and TestNG. Try Googling the phrase "java test framework".

Comment: @CoryKlein I have specifically stated "using eclipse alone". I am not looking for framework recommendation.

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question. I have retracted my close vote. Eclipse does appear to come with JUnit built-in. See [this good question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1962567/446554) and its answers.

Comment: this might be a hack. I can create multiple run configurations in eclipse for each testcase (will work for black box testing). Launch all run configs simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean by *simultaneously*? If that doesn't mean in parallel then you can always create a test suite or right click on the project and run as unit test.

Comment: @AleksandrM I meant launch all of them with just one click.I am alright with them running in parallel or one after the other. Thanks !!